# Draw random graph from adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, algebraic-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

In a circular area of radius $25$ miles, $32$ nodes are randomly placed. The distance $d$ between each pair of nodes can be the following:

1. $R_1 ~: 0 < d \leq 5$ miles
2. $R_2 ~: 5$ miles $< d \leq 10$ miles
3. $R_3 ~: 10$ miles $< d \leq 15$ miles
4. $R_4 ~: 15$ miles $< d$

Adjacency matrix $A$ is a $32\times32$ symmetric matrix with elements $a_{i,j}$ quantifies the relative distance between node $i$ and node $j$ and can take the following values:

1. if $d \in R_1 ~: a_{i,j}=1$
2. if $d \in R_2 ~: a_{i,j}=2$
3. if $d \in R_3 ~: a_{i,j}=3$
4. if $d \in R_4 ~: a_{i,j}=0$
5. and $a_{i,j}=0$ for $i=j$

An example of this adjacency matrix is as follows:

[image: image1]

Given such a matrix is there a simple algorithm to get random coordinates of all the $32$ nodes? I want to place all the nodes inside the circular region shown in the figure:

[image: image2]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Without at least *some* of the exact node locations, this question is hopeless because any rotation on the set of coordinates will preserve the relative distances. With some of the exact node locations, this problem is known as *network localization*; however, you have imperfect distance information, so I'm guessing that there are infinitely many solutions for each such adjacency matrix.

Comment: @gandalfbalrogslayer will the most connected node location be sufficient? Most connected node will be the row in adjacency matrix with most non zero elements. If I place it at the centre (0,0) ? Also I don't need a general solution. One of the infinitely many solutions and a intuitive way to reach that solution will solve my problem. What other information is required to solve this problem?